# powershell variable won't be used in second part of script

Tags: powershell

I'm learning power shell and I have problem with this code. when I parse it, it all works, but not together. what could be the problem? Thank you for answer.

```
$hotfix = read-host "Enter hotfixID"

Start-Process firefox.exe (get-hotfix | 
Where-Object -filter {$_.hotfixID -eq $hotfix} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption)
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works correctly here. Note that I don't have Firefox installed, but it works fine with iexplore. What issue are you experiencing?

Also, as @Colyn1337 stated, you do not need to use Where-Object; you can simplify this script as follows:

```
$Hotfix = Read-Host "Enter Hotfix ID"

Start-Process firefox.exe
(
    Get-HotFix -Id "$Hotfix" | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
)
```

EDIT: As discussed in the below comments, the issue was that the arguments do not work when called via `powershell.exe -command scriptname`. The solution would be to pass the arguments implicitly via ArgumentList:

```
$Hotfix = Read-Host "Enter Hotfix ID"

Start-Process firefox.exe -ArgumentList `
(
    Get-HotFix -Id "$Hotfix" | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Script looks nice this short. Find out, that problem isn't in code, but in how I start it. I want executable script like batch file. So I created shortcut "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "C:\Users\Isis\Desktop\hotfix.ps1" and it won't open adress, only firefox.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the argument isn't passed when called this way. I'll edit the fix into my answer for visibility.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got it sorted. Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem. (Click the check mark.)

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific hotfix, you'd want to try something lik this:

```
$hotFix = Read-Host "Enter hotfixID"
Get-Hotfix -Id $hotFix
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, creating a browser process is not necessary.

Comment: I want open URL stored in caption property, that's why I start firefox. I found out, that problem is in starting script through shortcut: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "C:\Users\Isis\Desktop\hotfix.ps1" adress won't open, but firefox does.